# Rewrite / Redirect Host With SSH Config File?

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration, ssh-tunnel, ssh-agent

My company has three separate jump hosts. Something like: `jump1.example.com`, `jump2.example.com`, and `jump3.example.com`

All internal servers must be accessed through these jumphosts:

```
local ---> jump1.example.com ---> internal.example.com
```

We have ***lots*** of internal servers, so to simplify I created a config file like so:

**.ssh/config**:

```
Host jump1.example.com jump2.example.com jump3.example.com
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand none

Host *.example.com
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    User sbarnett
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump1.example.com
```

Note that my public key is located on every one of these machines, so this setup works perfectly. I can type `ssh internal.example.com` and it will properly proxy through `jump1.example.com` and connect with my private key

Here's what I want to do, though: Instead of typing `jump1.example.com` or `internal.example.com`, I'd like to just type `ssh jump1` or `ssh internal`

I know that this can be configured per host like so:

```
Host internal
    HostName internal.example.com
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    User sbarnett
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump1.example.com
```

However if I try the much simpler:

```
Host internal
    HostName internal.example.com
```

Then my generic config options (under `*.example.com`) are not loaded when I try to use `ssh internal` -- so it doesn't use the proxy and doesn't use the identity file, preventing me from connecting.

Is there a way to say "if the host ***name*** is `*.example.com` (not necessarily the ***host***) then apply these settings"?

Bonus points for a way to redirect `*` to `*.example.com` if and only if `*` does not exist (e.g. - when connecting to `git@github.com` I don't want it to redirect to `git@github.com.example.com`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `CanonicalizeHostname`.

If you add these to the top of your .ssh/config, `ssh internal` will try to dns resolve your entry speculatively as internal.example.com, and if successful, it will process it matching `Host *.example.com`. The CanonicalDomains line can have multiple entries that are tried in order.

```
CanonicalDomains example.com
CanonicalizeHostname yes
```

Comment: So this seemed to half-work, with two weird quirks. First, after canonicalizing a host, it seemed to ignore some of my settings. I tried `ssh jump1` and it connected, but asked for a password (even though `ssh jump1.example.com` uses my private key). Second, it only seemed to canonicalize hosts without dots in them. I tried `ssh internal.server.1` and instead of connecting to `internal.server.1.example.com` it just failed, saying "Could not resolve hostname"

Comment: Doing some googling I found out I can fix the second issue with `CanonicalizeMaxDots X` (I used X = 3). Although it's still not using my private key to connect when I use the canonical domain

Comment: Might try with CanonicalizeHostname set to `always`.

Comment: Actually, you can ignore the other issue I had. I just discovered a stray `Host *\nPubkeyAuthentication no` in my ssh config (which was being overridden by `Host *.example.com\nPubkeyAuthentication yes` above). Ripped that out and it's now properly using my private key.

Comment: Wishing I could give a +2 to an answer. In just the last week this trick has saved me ***soooooooo*** much time and headache. I never even realized how much time was spent typing `.example.com` 86 times a day